# Why do I get the warning MATLAB:hg:DiceyTransformMatrix for this seemingly valid transform matrix?

Tags: matlab

Why do I get the warning `MATLAB:hg:DiceyTransformMatrix` for this seemingly valid transform matrix in Matlab when using `hgtransform`?

```
M = [ 992.0167e-003   -16.1520e-006  -126.1067e-003    -4.2912e-003;
       16.2941e-006     1.0000e+000    95.3293e-009    -5.6726e-009;
      126.1067e-003    -2.1494e-006   992.0167e-003  -357.0056e-003;
        0.0000e+000     0.0000e+000     0.0000e+000     1.0000e+000 ];
```

An example:

```
>> M = [ 992.0167e-003   -16.1520e-006  -126.1067e-003    -4.2912e-003;
       16.2941e-006     1.0000e+000    95.3293e-009    -5.6726e-009;
      126.1067e-003    -2.1494e-006   992.0167e-003  -357.0056e-003;
        0.0000e+000     0.0000e+000     0.0000e+000     1.0000e+000 ];
>> hgt = hgtransform ('Matrix', M)
Warning: The new value for the Matrix property may cause rendering problems
(Type "warning off MATLAB:hg:DiceyTransformMatrix" to suppress this warning.)

hgt = 

  Transform with properties:

    Children: [0×0 GraphicsPlaceholder]
     Visible: 'on'
     HitTest: 'on'
      Matrix: [4×4 double]

  Show all properties
```

When I actually apply this transform in the real code, I do not see any rendering problems.